# How to draw flow diagram with different shapes in latex?

Tags: flow-charts, box

I want to draw a block diagram given below. I have tried to draw it using online help but it is not working.

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
        \tikzset{block/.style= {draw, rectangle, align=center,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm},
        rblock/.style={draw, shape=rectangle,rounded corners=1.5em,align=center,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm},
        input/.style={ % requires library shapes.geometric
        draw,
        trapezium,
        trapezium left angle=60,
        trapezium right angle=120,
        minimum width=2cm,
        align=center,
        minimum height=1cm
    },
        }
        \node [rblock]  (start) {Start};
        \node [block, right =2cm of start] (acquire) {Acquire Image and Modify};
        \node [block, right =2cm of acquire] (rgb2gray) {RGB to Gray};
        \node [block, right =2cm of rgb2gray] (otsu) {Localized OTSU \\ Thresholding};
        

%% paths
        \path[draw,->] (start) edge (acquire)
                    (acquire) edge (rgb2gray)
                    (rgb2gray) edge (otsu)
                    (otsu.east) -| (right) -- (left) |- (gchannel)
                    (gchannel) edge (closing)
                    (closing) edge (NN)
                    (NN) edge (limit)
                    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like you didn't define right, left, gchannel, closing and NN as nodes. At least those lines won't compile for me in the last path statement. (If that's part of the problem, please update your code and indicate the remaining issue.) // Is it important that your sketch doesn't match the codes result?

Comment: I have compiled the above code in the overleaf, I am getting extra lines.

Comment: I have added the output also.

Comment: We've had several reports here suggesting that Overleaf tends to be "relaxed on LaTeX". So the save way is to compile on a local installation. // Don't know if I understand you: IF you do not define a node like {closing}, you can't draw to or from it, which results in compile errors.

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshot. Right, I obtain the 4 shapes/nodes. The through-lines are missing, because I had to delete those code lines to compile. So ... Overleaf is the trouble maker once again.

Comment: @MS-SPO Overleaf is not the trouble, if I compile the OP's MWE I got no output. Leaving out the undefined nodes on the path `-| (right) -- (left) |- (gchannel)
                    (gchannel) edge (closing)
                    (closing) edge (NN)
                    (NN) edge (limit)` it compiles fine with a correct output. The problem is in a part of MWE the OP didn't show.

Comment: Thanks @CarLaTeX. I did the same and get 4 objects in a line. With a change introduced days ago all it added was a kind of strike through by a path from left to right. The screenshot sketch is quite different. I wondered, how Overleaf could compile with the lines we both commented out.

Comment: @MS-SPO Overleaf does not compile with the lines we commented out. I have an Overleaf account and I tried. As "correct output" I intended without the line the crosses the nodes, of course, they are in a line.